# convert type "system collection generic.iList<long> to long[]"

Tags: c#, bing-api

Please help me i am integrating bing app in my application. I have got this error "system collection generic.iList<long> to long[]". Below is my AddCampaigns function:

```
static long[] AddCampaigns(long accountId, Campaign[] campaigns)
        {
            var request = new AddCampaignsRequest
            {
                // Set the header information.
                UserName = *******,
                Password = *******,
                DeveloperToken = DeveloperToken,
                CustomerAccountId = accountId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                AuthenticationToken = "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",
                // Set the request information.
                AccountId = accountId,
                Campaigns = campaigns
            };

            return _service.AddCampaigns(request).CampaignIds;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just call `.ToArray()` on the result.

Comment: @Leandro Seriously?  *This* is an interesting question to you?  Is that sarcasm?

Comment: @Leandro: Then you are lucky. There are a million of these questions on SO.

Comment: @Leandro I'm not sure what "interesting" means in relation to the post. Indeed one can consider it some sort of puzzle to find where error actually happen (instead of OP to point directly to line of code where it happens), but I'm not really sure this would be a good reason to *up*-vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ToArray()` LINQ [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from your title that `CampaignIds` is a `IList<long>` then you can simply use the Linq's [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) to fix the issue

```
using System.Linq;

//...
return _service.AddCampaigns(request).CampaignIds.ToArray();
```

If `CampaignIds` needs any sort of translation, add a [`.Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) before `ToArray()`

```
//...    
return _service.AddCampaigns(request).CampaignIds
    .Select(id => /** Some Translation work **/ )
    .ToArray();
```

You should also carefully consider the use of `Long[]` against a sinple `IEnumerable<long>` depending on usage - there is some overhead to using `.ToArray` that could be avoided if you don't need array-specific functionality out of the result.

Answer (score 0):

**You must convert list to array with**

```
.ToArray()
```

**method of List object.**

Suggestion:
By the way, are you sure you really need an array or a list or IEnumerable?